# c++ undefined reference to `main' while compiling

Tags: c++, makefile

After try to use this attached makefile the error that appears is :

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [Ass1F] Error 1
```

the makefile is :

```
all: Ass1F

Ass1F: bin/main.o bin/x.o bin/y.o bin/z.o bin/w.o
g++ -o bin/main.o bin/x.o bin/y.o bin/z.o bin/w.o

@echo 'Finished building target: Ass1F'
@echo ' '

bin/x.o: src/x.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/x.o src/x.cpp

bin/y.o: src/y.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/y.o src/y.cpp

bin/z.o: src/z.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/z.o src/z.cpp

bin/w.o: src/w.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/w.o   src/w.cpp

bin/main.o: src/main.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp

clean: 
rm -f bin/*
```

what should I do with this problem?
the reason is the makefile or something in the code?
just to let you know we used eclipse to write the code and everything work perfectly- no any bugs.

thanks

Comment: Your teacher might be very happy to get a program called `Ass*`

Comment: What is `-Linclude` supposed to do? That's a linker argument, which will be ignored because you use it when not doing any linking.  Do you mean `-Iinclude` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line `g++ -o bin/main.o bin/x.o bin/y.o bin/z.o bin/w.o` tries to create executable named `bin/main.o`, overwriting its previous contents.

It should be e.g. `g++ -o Ass1F bin/main.o bin/x.o bin/y.o bin/z.o bin/w.o`

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile recipe for `Ass1F` is incorrect, it doesn't specify the output file, os make uses `bin/main.o` as the output file instead of one of the input files.

You can simplify the makefile by using pattern rules (i.e. with wildcards) and using pre-defined variables such as `$@` (the name of the target) and `$^` (the list of prerequisites) and `CXX` (the C++ compiler):

```
CXXFLAGS  = -g -Wall -Weffc++
CPPFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS =

all: Ass1F

Ass1F: bin/main.o bin/x.o bin/y.o bin/z.o bin/w.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
        @echo 'Finished building target: Ass1F'
        @echo ' '

bin/%.o: src/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

clean: 
        rm -f bin/*
```